# Force of Gravity and $F=ma$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, free-body-diagram

Imagine a box on a table. It should have $F_g$ downward and $F_N$ upward.
(I do get that we have to add those forces.)
However $F=ma$ and the box's mass is constant.
How is $F_g=mg$ if the box's acceleration is $0m/s^2$?
Does the $m$ value gets bigger?

Comment: *I do get that we have to add those forces* And what happens when you add those (equal & opposite) forces? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than writing it as $F=ma$, write it as
${\bf F}_{\text{net}} = m {\bf a}$

That is, acceleration of the body is proportional to $|{\bf F}_{\text{net}}|$ and is in the direction of ${\bf F}_{\text{net}}$.
Acceleration is the result of the net force acting on the body (and not individual forces like ${\bf F}_{\text{g}}$), the ${\bf F}_{\text{net}}$, which is the vector sum of all the forces.

The law of gravity,  ${\bf F}_{\text{g}} = m {\bf g}$, tells us that the force due to gravity is proportional to the mass, and in the direction of the constant vector ${\bf g}$. It doesn't tell anything about other forces, or the ${\bf F}_{\text{net}}$.

Here, due to the normal force ${\bf F}_{\text{N}}$ - it is NOT the case that ${\bf F}_{\text{net}} = {\bf F}_{\text{g}}$ , hence the ${\bf g}$ is not acceleration of the body.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of understanding, I will use Qualitative Newtonian analysis in the most simplified manner.

4 forces act in a situation of a box which is placed on the table.

**1. Downward Gravitational force exerted by earth upon box**

**2. Upward Gravitational force exerted by box upon earth**

**3. Downward Force exerted by box on the table**
This force is exerted because *earth is pulling box towards itself*.
Since the table is in the way, the *box will exert a force downwards
upon it.*

**4. Upward Reaction force exerted by table upon the box.**
This force *stops the box from falling freely* and piercing through the
table.

Now 2 forces are acting upon the box **Force 1** and **Force 4**. Both have equal magnitude and opposite direction. Hence vector sum of force equals zero. Since there is **no resultant force**, there will be no resultant acceleration i.e. a=0m/s.

This is because Newton's Second Law states:
**When a *resultant force* is exerted upon a mass. It produces an acceleration. The product of the mass and acceleration equals resultant force. The direction of acceleration is in the direction of resultant force.**

Force 1 is the weight while Force 4 is the normal reaction force which add up to zero. Hence zero acceleration and the box remains stationary.

Answer (score 0):

The $g$ in the $F_g=mg$ formula refers to the 'acceleration due to gravity', $9.81ms^{-2}$, not the acceleration of the box when it's on the table.

It's used to work out the weight of the box, so $F_g=mg$ is often written as $W=mg$.